# DBI and fork don't work on Windows

Tags: multithreading, perl, dbi

I used this article: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=594175 to write code, combining DBI with fork. It works on Linux, but doesn't work on Windows XP. I am using Active state Perl v5.10.0 MSWin32-x86-multi-thread, DBD::mysql v4.011.

On Linux Perl v5.16.1 i486-linux-thread-multi DBD::mysql v4.021.

Code. dbi_fork.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;
require "mysql.pl";

my $dbh = connect_mysql();

if (fork()) {
    $dbh->do("UPDATE articles SET title='parent' WHERE id=1");
}
else {
    my $dbh_child = $dbh->clone();
    $dbh->{InactiveDestroy} = 1;
    undef $dbh;
    $dbh_child->do("UPDATE articles SET title='child' WHERE id=2");
}
```

mysql.pl:

```
sub connect_mysql
{
    my $user_db = 'user';
    my $password_db = 'secret';
    my $base_name = 'test';
    my $mysql_host_url = 'localhost';

    my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:$base_name:$mysql_host_url";
    my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $user_db, $password_db) or die $DBI::errstr;

    return $dbh;
}

1;
```

articles table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `articles`;
CREATE TABLE `articles` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of articles
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `articles` VALUES ('1', 'title1');
INSERT INTO `articles` VALUES ('2', 'title2');
```

On Windows it gives an error:

```
$ perl ./dbi_fork.pl
DBD::mysql::db clone failed: handle 2 is owned by thread 2344b4 not current
thread 1a45014 (handles can't be shared between threads and your driver may
need a CLONE method added) at ./dbi_fork.pl line 14.
```

How to fix?

Comment: **(1)** You can't compare the behaviour of the Windows version with the Linux version; there are too many variables here. You could reduce the number of variables by installing a perl5.16 on the XP box (e.g. [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/)), and installing the same version of DBD::mysql. **(2)** Anyway, Windows does not have a native `fork`. Instead, it is emulated using threads. It looks like the problem could be circumvented by cloning the handle before the `fork` and having each side close the unused handle. Or the child runs `connect_mysql` anew to obtain a second handle.

Comment: @amon: You should publish that as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no such thing as `fork` on Windows. It's a feature specific to unix systems. Perl emulates it using threads on Windows, and this is causing problems.

Rather than trying to recreate an existing connection, simply create the connections in the task.

In other words, use

```
if (fork()) {
    my $dbh = connect_mysql();
    $dbh->do(...);
} else {
    my $dbh = connect_mysql();
    $dbh->do(...);
}
```

Comment: I didn't notice you were using a weird hack to try to create a new connection in the child process -- I guess I stopped paying attn after I noticed you only connected once -- so my explanation was a bit off, but the solution still applies. Updated explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution - every thread creates it's own connection:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;
require "mysql.pl";

if (fork()) {
    my $dbh = connect_mysql();
    $dbh->do("UPDATE articles SET title='parent' WHERE id=1");
}
else {
    my $dbh = connect_mysql();
    $dbh->do("UPDATE articles SET title='child' WHERE id=2");
}
```

Comment: This is the best approach.